# The sum V for a twelve clock vector when the centre is moved from [0,0] to 6:00

Tags: linear-algebra

I have noticed that there is already a question "Linear Algebra - Clock Question" that has been closed with an answer.
I have the exact same question because I do not understand the answer to the closed question (which has been copied from the solution to the problems in the book).

Let me explain my problem in details.

This is the figure used for the question:
[Twelve clock vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPXrm.png)

The questions has four parts:

Part a) asks the user to calculate the sum V of the twelve vectors that go from the centre of the clock to the hours 1:00, 2:00, .... 12:00. The answer here is the "zero" vector.

Part b) and c) asks the user to solve 2 other questions regarding the figure.

A following question asks the user to suppose that the twelve vectors in the figure start from 6:00 at the bottom of the figure instead of the centre (0,0). It additionally sets the vector to 12:00 to (0,2) - double the size (since in the diagram it seems like the vector to 12:00 from the middle is (0, 1)). The user is then asked to find out the new sum V of the twelve vectors.

My answer is again the "zero" vector. The solution accompanying the book is (0, 12).

How did I arrive at the answer:
1) Keeping the size of all the vectors the same (other than 12:00) and starting from 6:00 I kept joining 11 vectors (starting with 1:00) till I arrived at a position directly below (by [0, -1]) the 6:00 vector.
2) I then added the 12:00 vector [0, 2] which takes me again to the centre of the clock - the "zero" vector.

The solution accompanying the book says [0, 12]. How do they arrive at this value?

Kind regards,
Sami

Comment: Let $P_i$ be the point associated with hour $i$. Note that the vector from $P_6$ to $P_i$ can be written as a sum of vectors, the first from $P_6$ to $(0,0)$, then from $(0,0)$ to $P_i$.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you pjs36.

I thought about the problem again after I posted it.
My initial assumption that the size of all other vectors (other than 12:00) remain the same was incorrect.

All the vectors change in size starting from 12:00 - increases in y the amount that the starting point moved down from [0,0] i.e. [0,1]. All the others also increase in y by the same amount. So the new clock would actually look like ( A line from 6:00 to 1:00, a line from 6:00 to 2:00 ... a line from 6:00 to 12:00 ). Their sum V would then be [0,12] since all the y's are >= 0.

Made my day!!! Thanks!!!
Sami

Comment: Another good way to see how the shift affects things, well done!

Comment: @pjs36 what would be a good way to visualize this problem? When origin is moved from (0,0) to 6:00 at the bottom, it is easy to visualize what happens to vector to 12:00 as it doubles from (0,1) to (0,2). But how does this affect vector to 6:00? Before shoft, it would have been (0,-1) and now?? Is it still (0,-1) as the magnitude and direction remains the same?